# How to update a record in a table using subtraction when another table gets an inserted record?

Tags: t-sql

I've got a dbo.Warehouse table which contains ProductID's and Quantities and a dbo.Orders table which contains the Orders made for each product etc.
I've created a trigger that will update the Warehouse table when a new record is inserted into the Order table,
However, the problem is that when a new records is inserted, all the records get updated instead of just the 1 which is new, basically if I have already 2 previous orders placed for ProductID 3 and 2 Orders already placed for ProductID 2, not just ProductID 3 quantity values get updated (deducted), but also the ProductID 2 ones which have previously been deducted, please advise what I can do with my code to make this work, thanks.

```
ALTER TRIGGER Trg_AI_UpdateQty ON dbo.Orders
AFTER INSERT
AS


IF EXISTS (SELECT A.ProductID, A.Qty
       FROM dbo.Warehouse AS A
       INNER JOIN dbo.Orders AS B  ON A.ProductID = B.ProductID
       WHERE B.OrderQty > A.Qty
         )

BEGIN 
RAISERROR ('You do not have enough Products in stock, please order more', 1, 1)
END

ELSE

BEGIN

UPDATE B
SET B.Qty = (B.Qty - A.OrderQty) 
FROM dbo.Orders AS A
INNER JOIN dbo.Warehouse AS B  ON A.ProductID = B.ProductID
WHERE A.ProductID = B.ProductID

END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join on the inserted table not the underlying table the trigger is on SO:

Here is more information on the special deleted and inserted tables

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx

```
ALTER TRIGGER Trg_AI_UpdateQty ON dbo.Orders
AFTER INSERT
AS


IF EXISTS (SELECT A.ProductID, A.Qty
       FROM dbo.Warehouse AS A
       INNER JOIN inserted AS B  ON A.ProductID = B.ProductID
       WHERE B.OrderQty > A.Qty
         )

BEGIN 
RAISERROR ('You do not have enough Products in stock, please order more', 1, 1)
END

ELSE

BEGIN

UPDATE B
SET B.Qty = (B.Qty - A.OrderQty) 
FROM inserted AS A
INNER JOIN dbo.Warehouse AS B  ON A.ProductID = B.ProductID
WHERE A.ProductID = B.ProductID

END
```

Comment: Oh jeez, stupid me..I should have thought of the inserted table :( thanks a mill Gratzy !!! it's appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ALTER TRIGGER Trg_AI_UpdateQty ON dbo.Orders
AFTER INSERT
AS
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
       FROM dbo.Warehouse AS A
       INNER JOIN inserted AS B  ON A.ProductID = B.ProductID
       WHERE B.OrderQty > A.Qty)
BEGIN 
RAISERROR ('You do not have enough Products in stock, please order more', 1, 1)
END
ELSE
BEGIN
UPDATE B
SET B.Qty = (B.Qty - A.OrderQty) 
FROM inserted AS A
INNER JOIN dbo.Warehouse AS B  ON A.ProductID = B.ProductID
WHERE A.ProductID = B.ProductID 
END
```

On a side note try to `select 1` when you are using `if exists`

Comment: Thanks R.T. will keep in mind :), I assume it's performance related?